# Changing img source by clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loops

I want to replace the number in the image src (eg. from eyes1 to eyes2) when I click a button.

```
moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
    var eyesImg = $('#eyesImg').get(0).src;
    console.log(eyesImg) // <--- folder/folder/folder/img/eyes1.png

    //iterate with one (eg. eyes1.png to eyes2.png) and change the src?
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on pmandell answer, you could also keep an increment (if that's what you want to do)

Also, it seems your image has an ID of eyesImg, so I've taken that into account also

```
var counter = 0;

moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
    $('#eyesImg').attr('src','folder/folder/folder/img/eyes' + counter + '.png');
    counter++
}
```

**Edit**

Here's an example involving cats. Cats always help
http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/6Cve9/

Comment: Thanks, the img src is changing as supposed. However, the actual image isn't changed even though I can see in the code that the img src is actually changed. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('src','new_src_string');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
    $(this).prop('src','folder/folder/folder/img/eyes2.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 var image =  $(this).attr('src');
 //alert(image);
 var newimage = image.replace('1.png','2.png');
$(this).attr('src',newimage );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/ADMVx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#eyesImg').attr('src',$('eyesImg').attr('src').replace('eyes1','eyes2'));
```